# How can I renew an admin certificate for a Hyperledger Fabric orderer / peer while the admin certificate nearly expire

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

In the Hyperledger Fabric official website, it states to use the fabric-ca-client reenroll if a certificate is about to expire. I tried to reenoll the certificates but an x.509 error occurred:

[grpc] createTransport -> DEBU bab grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {orderer:7050 0  }. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority". Reconnecting...

I have used the same CA to reenroll the certificate, I don't know why "unknown authority" error shown.

It would be grateful if anyone can give me a full steps for replacing the admin certificate for the Hyperledger Fabric.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [akc-dcm-cli](https://github.com/Akachain/akc-dcm-cli). It support renew user of Hyperledger Fabric by running command:

```sh
dcm certificate renew  --parent-cert=../data/intermediate-ca/signcerts/ica-cert.pem 
--parent-private-key=../data/intermediate-ca/keystore/ica-key.pem 
--old-cert=../data/peer/output/peer-cert.pem 
--old-private-key=../data/peer/keystore/peer-key.pem 
--output=../data/peer/output/renew-peer-cert.pem
--days=365
```

- `parent-cert` and `parent-private-key` are key-pair of CA
- `old-cert` and `old-private-key` are key-pair of expired user
- `output` is the path of new cert

After renewing the cert, you replace the expired cert of the user with the new cert. Keep current private key of user' cert

Comment: Many thanks for your great reply. May I know that should I need to update the channel configure too after I replaced new certs in crypto-config folder ?

Comment: No. If you keep the old private key, the new cert will work normally same like expired cert

Comment: Oh, I just test it on fabric v1.4. But I think it works on both versions because it uses openssl lib to renew the cert